# Jenkins Redirects to Http after Login

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins

Apologies if this isn't the right place to post this question but I have a Jenkins container running on an ec2. Both listen on 8080. I have an NLB that listens on 443.  When I log into to my https://jenkins.xyz.com, it redirects to http://jenkins.xyz.com. I get an error as nothing is listening on 80. If I manually change http to https after logging in, I'm in and just it works fine, although I get "reverse proxy is broken" error in Configure Jenkins. Tried a different container but still the same issue. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to solve my issue following the instructions in this article:

http://code.haleby.se/2016/01/22/enable-ssl-in-jenkins-in-docker/

Just had to give the jenkins user (UID) permissions to the directory containing the cert on the host (which I didn't see in the article but might be mentioned).